# why woocommerce doesn't allow guest check out?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm managing a wordpress website which runs its shop using woocommerce and it doesn't allow guest check out, it doesn't even show the price of products before logging in!

the "enable guest checkout" option is enabled in woocommerce settings, my guess is that some piece of code in the theme or plugins causes this problem, what's the best approach to determine where the problem roots from?

Comment: I would try contacting their customer support if you haven't modified any code.

Comment: Try by switching off plugins one by one, and changing to a default theme